# remote phpMyAdmin automatically logs out at first click

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have ssh access on two remote virtual machines running Centos 7. The first hosts Apache 2, PHP 5.4 and phpMyAdmin 4.4. The second hosts MySQL 5.5. I created a MySQL user that is allowed to remotely connect to the databases I've created. I can access phpMyAdmin and login using these credentials, and I can see the databases in the home page. However, when I click any button in phpMyadmin (settings, one of the databases etc.) I automatically get logget out. This happens on Firefox. On Opera, I don't get logged out but when I click, nothing happens.

UPDATE: the buttons work if I open them in a new tab. However, I cannot execute queries.

This is what the Opera's console shows when I click on "settings":
[image]

This used to happen with MySQL 5.7 as well. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe cookies are disabled on Firefox?

Comment: Enable cookies if disabled. Clear your cookies for that site, and try again.

Comment: This solution does not work. I read somewhere that maybe it has to do with the profiling feature of phpMyAdmin, but I am cannot disable it since the SQL "go" button doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the problem disappeared after I installed the SSL certificate on the server running phpMyAdmin.